# Nan is being set in json model when trying to bind with odata response

Tags: javascript, json, odata, sapui5

I am creating a restructured json model in our sapui5 app wherein the data is being received from the odata response. I am using the json.setproperty() method.

if i try n access the value with following methods

```
    var two = 2;
    var test = "Count"
    var three = test+two
    alert(odata.results[0][three]);
```

correct value is being alerted with object notation as against Nan being alerted if dot notation was used.

so in a loop im trying to fill the content of the json

```
    for(var i=0;i<=count-2;i++){
        var z = "Count"+i;  
        countjson.setProperty("/data/data/"+i+"/Count",odata.results[0].z);
        countjson.setProperty("/data/data/"+i+"/Count",odata.results[0][z]);                            

  }
```

Nan is being returned when im trying with the dot notation and undefined is being returned with object notation.

if i hardcode the path i.e odata.results[0].Count4 i am getting the 4th element from the odata resp and getting set in all fields of the new json.

Please help me with the above.

Best regards
archit

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a multidimensional array like that. Instead try using this -
`odata.results[0][odata.results[0].indexOf(three)]`

Comment: _"You cannot access a multidimensional array like that"_ - like what?

Comment: Try with capital O indexOf

Comment: thanks it was caps. a strange thing that is happening is when i use the   
var three defined in upper scope which is nothing but var two = 2;
    var test = "Count";   var three = test+two;(in obj notation) i am getting the value of Count2 thats there in the response but when i am trying to cr8 such a var in the for loop and using it its giving undefined.                    var z =  "Count";
var y = i;
var zz = z+y; & using odata.results[0][zz] is returning undefined.

Comment: In for loop also you should use results[0][results[0].indexOf(zz)]

Comment: Still facing the same error. this is wat im trying in loop                                                            lpdata.results[0][lpdata.results[0].indexOf("Count4")] or (zz) both are returning lpdata.results[0].indexOf is not a function.